# std::rename() file wont work when using a char variable as arguments (string converted to char)

Tags: c++, string, char

I tried it without adding the `"\""` on the beginning and end of the string `tablename4` and `tablename5` before converting it to char, and the `rename()` function still wouldn't work. It does work by just putting in the actual file name as rename() arguments, but thats not what i want, i want to use char variables

**Full compiling code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>  
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using std::string;

int main()
{

    std::string tablename4 = "hello.txt";
    ifstream in4(tablename4);
    ofstream out8("temp2.txt");

    std::string convertthis2;
    convertthis2 = "\"" + tablename4 + "\"";
    char * tochar2 = new char[convertthis2.length()];
    strcpy_s(tochar2, (convertthis2.length() + 1), convertthis2.c_str());

    std::string convertthis3;
    std::string tablename5 = "temp2.txt";
    convertthis3 = "\"" + tablename5 + "\"";
    char * tochar3 = new char[convertthis3.length()];
    strcpy_s(tochar3, (convertthis3.length() + 1), convertthis3.c_str());
    in4.close();
    out8.close();
    rename(tochar3, tochar2);

    //below is testing to see if it converted right, but these print out fine, as "hello.txt" and "temp2.txt"
    //but i tried it with and without the quotation marks, rename() still doesnt work
    cout << tochar2 << "     " << tochar3;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the error handling?

Comment: Why are you using`new char[ ]` at all in your program?  There is such a thing as `+=` for strings as well as `string::cstr()` to obtain a `const char*`.  No need to resort to `strcpy_s`.

Comment: Are you sure the program is run in the directory where your file is?

Comment: Yes, its renaming it when i just put in the actual file names instead of the char variable name containing the file name that was converted from string

Comment: @donnie Why do you need to put quotes around the file name?  The `rename()` function doesn't require them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplifiying slightly and correcting the 2 bugs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using std::string;

int main()
{

    std::string tablename4 = "hello.txt";
    ifstream in4(tablename4);
    ofstream out8("temp2.txt");

    std::string convertthis2 = string("\"") + tablename4 + "\"";

    std::string tablename5 = "temp2.txt";
    std::string convertthis3 = string("\"") + tablename5 + "\"";
    in4.close();
    out8.close();
    rename(convertthis3.c_str(), convertthis2.c_str());

    //below is testing to see if it converted right, but these print out fine, as "hello.txt" and "temp2.txt"
    //but i tried it with and without the quotation marks, rename() still doesnt work
    cout << convertthis2 << "     " << convertthis3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that you're allocating an array of bytes which is equal to the length of the `string` objects and then using those arrays as c-style strings. However a c-style string must have a terminating zero, which you do not add - hence undefined behaviour.

Note the use of the .c_str() member variable above. It does exactly what you want - makes a std::string look like a c-style string in a safe way.

Something to take away from this is the idea that if you find yourself writing c-code, it's because you would benefit from reading the stl documentation.

Comment: Do i just add the ` \0 `  on the end of the `string convertthis` Do i do this:       `convertthis2 = string("\"") + tablename4 + "\"" + "\0"; ` The solution you provided is still not renaming the file

Comment: @donnie `std::string` itself is not null terminated.  The `c_str()` function returns a const char * that is null-terminated.  Second, why not do a sanity test and hard-code the names of the files in the rename() call?  If that doesn't rename the file, then no amount of work using `std::string` is going to help.

Comment: Well i want the user to input the strings using `cin`. This solution still does not rename the file

Comment: it's probably because you are adding the un-necessary quotation marks.

Comment: What does inputting with `cin` have anything to do with knowing what a `std::string` is?  And if you want the user to enter a file with spaces, use `std::getline(cin, string_variable)`, not  just `cin >>`.  The quoutes the user needs on the command-line if so that the command-line processor (CMD.EXE) doesn't get confused.  It has no bearing on what you need to send to `rename`.

Comment: Well, as the old joke goes "doctor, it hurts when I move my arm like this", the doctor says, "well don't move your arm like that!".  In other words, *remove those unnecessary quotes*.  Why insist on using them when they are not needed, and may indeed be the cause of the problem?